How to fetch products from Shopify Storefront API
I am having an issue retrieving data from my Shopify Storefront API. I am using graphql to query my products and product details but for some reason none of the information is displaying on my desired page. I'm no longer getting any error messages though so I really don't know what is going on. Here is my code below.
My shopifyApi.js file:
import axios from 'axios';

const shopifyApi = axios.create({
  method: 'POST',
  baseURL: `https://<MyShopifyStore>/api/2024-10/graphql.json`,
  headers: {
    'X-Shopify-Storefront-Access-Token': '',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
});

export const fetchProducts = async () => {
  const query = `{
    products(first: 10) {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          title
          descriptionHtml
          variants(first: 1) {
            edges {
              node {
                id
                price
                sku
                image {
                  originalSrc
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }`;

  const response = await shopifyApi.post('', { query });
  return response?.data?.data?.products?.edges;
}

Here is my Products.jsx file:
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { fetchProducts } from '../../../api/shopifyApi';
...

const Products = () => {

  const [productsList, setProductsList] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getProducts = async () => {
      const data = await fetchProducts();
      setProductsList(data);
    };
    getProducts();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="product-container">
      {productsList?.map(({ node }) => (
        <div key={node.id}>
          <h2>{node.title}</h2>
          <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: node.descriptionHtml}}></div>
          <img src={node.variants.edges[0].node.image.originalSrc} alt={node.title}/>
          <p>£{node.variants.edges[0].node.price}</p>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Products

I would like to mention that the value for productList has been assigned as never[]. I assume this might be the reason it is not working but if not, what could it be? Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you.

I would suggest you to use liquid or fetch api for fetching products on the storefront.
